# Scala and Node.js

Tags: node.js, scala, serialization, socket.io, marshalling

We chose Node.js for our web project, but there are many computational tasks for which we would prefer Scala. We are highly concerned about speed, what is the best way to call a Scala "worker" from Node.js in an asynchronous non-blocking way?

Comment: So you want to call from Node.js to Scala (on the JVM)? In that case I guess the best would be to stay on the JVM: http://nodyn.io/ or something based on Rhino/Nashorn (http://blog.jonasbandi.net/2014/03/running-nodejs-applications-on-jvm-with.html).

Comment: You leverage no benefits running node with nodyn. It's not uncommon to run long-running jobs on workers, and if the worker is doing lots of processing you'd probably benefit from moving away from javascript.

Answer (score 1):

When queuing jobs its best to have some kind of Broker like a message queue or a job queue. Redis is a popular choice, as it can also be used for caching, and storing data in memory. RabbitMQ is another common choice. The nice thing about having a Broker is it can hold the job until a worker pulls it out of queue when ever it has available resources. A broker also acts as a load balancer in a sense, where it holds jobs and you can have multiple worker nodes grabbing jobs allowing for high availability, scalability, and parallel processing.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should not be so concerned about speed; in my experience concerns like readability and maintainability are more important in almost all projects.

For short-lived "remote procedure calls" of at most a few seconds, I would tend to use [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/), which has libraries for Javascript and the JVM ([Scrooge](https://github.com/twitter/scrooge) is an alternative Scala implementation, oriented towards writing async backends using Twitter's Finagle futures library), allowing nonblocking calls; by using Thrift you get strongly typed interface definitions that are engineered for forward compatibility, and you know exactly what changes you can make to the interface without breaking compatibility.

Alternatively one could use an ordinary HTTP ("REST") interface; node is oriented towards making async HTTP calls, and libraries like Spray make it easy to offer a high-performance, async HTTP interface in Scala.

For longer-running "batch" tasks where you're less concerned about latency and more about reliability, it's probably better to use a dedicated task queue as @tsutrzl suggests.

Comment: You need to be more explicit and specific. Why would you have node handle all I/O, when Scala can do higher-performance I/O? What are your actual constraints and criteria? (no-one can tell you what's "best" without knowing what you care about)